# KendoUI/Angular grid: can filter by string, cannot by number

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ckn93Cp8bl8XLDQbxyin?p=preview) I have a KendoUI/Angular grid with two columns; the first column contains numbers and the second strings.

When I filter the second column (the strings) I have no issues, however when I try to filter the first column (the numbers) I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Is it possible to filter by numbers or only strings?

Note that [in this Kendo UI example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization) there's a filter by date/time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem: I defined the column type=number in datasource.schema.model:

```
$scope.ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    model: {
       id: "cols",
       fields: {
          quantity: {
              type: "number"
          },
          name: {
             type: "string"
         }
        }
      }
    },
    data:.........
});
```